# How to extend text input in html?

Tags: html, replit

Honestly i was using w3schools so idk what to do.

On my repl BatCoder its a repl where you can code Bat files and save them.
And now i need to extend the text input!

Now can anyone help me? I am a learning coder.

No errors just idk what to do.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<marquee direction = "right">Welcome to BATCoder by <a href="https://replit.com/@yooperhunter8">@yooperhunter8 </a>on replit.</marquee>
<header>
Input:
<input type="text"></input>
</header>
</style>
```

Comment: can you please explain what does 'extend text input' mean? if you need bigger input text which can have multiple line at a time, you can use `textarea`. tag

Comment: What do you mean by extent? Make it wider/taller? Also, you ar missing the html and body tags, and have a closing style tag, without the opening tag!

Answer (score 0):

Use `<textarea></textarea>` instead of `<input>`